# Nested Looping in R

Tags: r

I want to compare the email ID in both the files and if they match, then find out the difference between the dates. There may be many to many occurrences (email id could be repeated in both the files)

I tried using nested looping and IF conditions.

```
 library(openair)
 pp<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
 pe<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
 for(i in 1 : nrow(pp))
 {
   for(j in 1 : nrow(pe))
   {
     if(is.na(pp$RIDER_EMAIL) == is.na(pe$RIDER_EMAIL))
     {
       x[i][j] = pp$Created.Date2-pe$Expired.Date
     }
   }
 }
```

I expected a difference between the dates if the email ID is found. it could be like 0, -2, etc

Getting below error message

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, j, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  : 

  replacement has 22359 rows, data has 7349
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(pp$RIDER_EMAIL) == is.na(pe$RIDER_EMAIL) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In if (is.na(pp$RIDER_EMAIL) == is.na(pe$RIDER_EMAIL)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In Ops.factor(pp$Created.Date2, pe$Expired.Date) :
  ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: It's difficult to help without example data, but your code has a lot of issues. In particular, the `if()` comparison doesn't make sense and `x` is undefined. But nested loops are not a good solution here. Better to join the two data frames by email ID, then calculate the date difference in a new column. I'd look at `dplyr` joins and `mutate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Note the following things in the code below. I don't know if it actually works with your data because you're not providing any sample dataset (Please do it next time).

1. I tend to save data into lists since these are more versatile.
2. `pp$RIDER_EMAIL[i] != pe$RIDER_EMAIL[j]` is the same as asking if those two elements are different.
3. Don't forget to use `i`'s and `j`'s (or really any variable) when declared in loops.

```
    library(openair)
     pp<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
     pe<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)

    x<-list()
    y<-list()
     for(i in 1 : nrow(pp))
     {
       for(j in 1 : nrow(pe))
       {
         if(pp$RIDER_EMAIL[i] != pe$RIDER_EMAIL[j])
         {
           x[[j]] = pp$Created.Date2[i]-pe$Expired.Date[j]
         }
       }
      y[[i]]<-x
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, creating a reproducible example will help you get answers faster. Here I've created that for you. In this answer, I'm assuming you know how to deal with dates, and am just showing the solution for doing a many to many join of two tables and calculating the difference between two fields.

First create some fake data. Note that for the date field I'm just using an integer.

```
# Create fake data
library(tibble)
mail1 <- tribble(
  ~emailID, ~date,
  "a", 12,
  "a", 13,
  "c", 12,
  "d", 12,
)

mail2 <- tribble(
  ~emailID, ~date,
  "a", 1,
  "a", 2,
  "c", 1,
  "d", 1,
)
```

Now, to solve the question. In the output compare dataset, there is a column called difference that has the difference between the two dates for all matching values of emailID.

```
library(dplyr)

# rename the date column in the second dataset, this helps with the merge. 
mail2 <- mail2 %>% 
  rename(date2 = date)

# Merge, note row inflation through many to many match, and calculate the difference.
compare <- 
  full_join(mail1, mail2, by = "emailID") %>% 
  mutate(difference = date - date2)
```